# Linking array of titles to other JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

and thanks in advance.
I have a web page of articles titles. My JSON file is in this format:

```
[
    {
        "title": "title 1",
        "date": "date 1",
        "author": "Jane doe",
        ...etc...
    },
    {
        "title": "title 2",
        "date": "date 2",
        "author": "Jane doe 2",
        ...etc...
    }
]
```

tableofcontents.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="TableofContentController">
    <div class="medium-12 columns" role="content">
        <div class="medium-9 columns">
            <article>
                <div class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
                        <a ui-sref="articles">{{article.title}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>  
                </div>    
            </article>                   
        </div>
```

I have a separate article.html template that I want to load the rest of the JSON file to. So I have a list of all the titles, and if someone clicks on "title 1", it will take them to the article template. But how do I link all the other json data (date, author, article body, etc.) correctly when they click on the link? I assume functionality will be in the controller, but I haven't been able to find examples of what I'm looking for. Thanks!

app.js file, in case it's important

```
var webApp = angular.module('webApp', ['ui.router']);


webApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    'use strict';

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');


    $stateProvider
        // homepage state
        .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        })
        // main article page state
        .state('articles', {
        url: '/articles/{{article.title}}',
        controller: 'ArticlesController',
        controllerAs: 'articles',
        templateUrl: 'templates/articles.html'
        })
        // about page state
        .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html'
        })
        // table of contents page state
        .state('content', {
        url: '/content',
        controller: 'TableofContentController',
        controllerAs: 'content',
        templateUrl: 'templates/tableofcontent.html'
        });

}); 

webApp.controller('TableofContentController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('articles.json')
       .then(function(res){
          $scope.articles = res.data;    
        });
});
```

Comment: Use a service to share data across controllers

Comment: Hi, I did add a service, and I can now use that service to share data across controllers. I'm still confused about how exactly to link the correct data though. How do I link this list of things: 
                        <li ng-repeat="article in articles">
                        <a ui-sref="articles">{{article.title}}</a>
                        </li>
so that the proper article shows up when they click on a link?